CodeCommit Create Repo Error: CreateRepository request is not allowed because there is no existing repository in this AWS account or AWS Organization
Attempting to create first repo in AWS CodeCommit and get the same error whether from console or CLI:
Console:
CreateRepository request is not allowed because there is no existing repository in this AWS account or AWS Organization
CLI:
An error occurred (OperationNotAllowedException) when calling the CreateRepository operation: CreateRepository request is not allowed because there is no existing repository in this AWS account or AWS Organization
Attempted Console and CLI.
Tried IAM user first, then tried root user.

I'm experiencing the exact same issue. I tried to create my first repository in CodeCommit today and received the same error, both in the console and CLI. I also tried with an IAM user and with the root user, without success. It seems to be a recent problem with the AWS service. I'll be keeping an eye out for any solution you find.

Just yesterday I ran into the same problem, and there's next to nothing mentioned online about this issue, adding this here so I can come back to this if I found anything.

You might want to read this thread:
https://repost.aws/questions/QUshILm0xbTjWJZSD8afYVgA/codecommit-cannot-create-a-repository

And FYI: S3 Select, CloudSearch, Cloud9, SimpleDB, Forecast, Data Pipeline, and CodeCommit are EOL

The issue you're experiencing is due to a recent change in AWS CodeCommit's service policy. According to an official AWS response:
As of June 6, 2024, AWS CodeCommit has stopped onboarding new customers. Only customers with existing repositories in AWS CodeCommit can create additional repositories.
This change doesn't affect current workloads using AWS CodeCommit. If you need to use AWS CodeCommit in a new AWS account within your AWS Organization, you can request an evaluation for allowlisting the new account.
For alternatives, AWS recommends using Amazon CodeCatalyst, GitLab, GitHub, or another third-party source provider. AWS has provided a blog post describing how to migrate your repository to these solutions.
AWS will continue to invest in security, availability, and performance improvements for CodeCommit and provide support, but they don't plan to introduce new features except for security and availability updates.
If you still need to use CodeCommit, you can submit a support case to request allowlisting, providing justification and confirming that your organization was a CodeCommit customer before July 25, 2024.
(This response was translated using AI. Credit and thanks to user @omar-tarek for providing the reference link: post)

As mentioned by @bypabloc_ , AWS CodeCommit has been discontinued:

After careful consideration, we have made the decision to close new customer access to AWS CodeCommit, effective July 25, 2024. AWS CodeCommit existing customers can continue to use the service as normal. AWS continues to invest in security, availability, and performance improvements for AWS CodeCommit, but we do not plan to introduce new features.

Here's the official announcement with instructions on how to migrate from AWS CodeCommit to another Git provider (such as GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket and so on).
I have also written an article titled AWS CodeCommit: Why Amazon’s Git Service Never Took Off which you might find helpful.
